# kotlin coroutine - what is default scope?

Tags: kotlinx.coroutines

How does coroutines default scope work if i do not specify anything. lets take a look at this example:

```
class MyAppCompatActivity:AppCompatActivity{
fun getContact() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val contact = contacts.getContact() // suspended function
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
               phoneContact.value = contact }
        }
    }
}
```

which simply updates the UI when a contact is retrieved.  this is added to the global scope of so the coroutine life span can be that of the entire application.

but lets do the same thing again without a globalScope:

```
class MyAppCompatActivity:AppCompatActivity{
fun getContact() {
        launch {
            val contact = contacts.getContact() // suspended function
            withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
               phoneContact.value = contact }
        }
    }
}
```

what is the lifespan of getContact now that i have removed the globalScope ? is it tied to the MyAppCompatActivity scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will fail to compile because `launch` must be called on a `CoroutineScope` object. This object specifies the lifespan of the coroutine. Since your activity does not implement a scope it will fail to compile or call a completely unrelated `launch` function.

Comment: Is there no default? I am able to run the code ok without declaration of a scope

Comment: Then you're probably still using the experimental API, which had a global `launch` which uses an internal scope by default. The release version removed this function by having it always require a scope to call `launch`.

Comment: this is really good to know thanks.  so am i right that as along as the scope variable i declare is not garbage collected (or released) that the coroutine will be alive still, right ?

Comment: Each context will be internally assigned a `Job` which controls the running of the coroutine. While the job is active and the coroutine has not finished by itself it will still be alive.

Comment: You can just instantiate a CoroutineScope, passing only a CoroutineContext (could be just a dispatcher) into it, what are the default "Job" aspects of such a CoroutineScope? What is its lifecycle bound to, the process?

Comment: The lifetime is determined by the scope and its parent, if you create a new `CoroutineScope` with no parent job it'll stay around until all references are gone. Effectively that means process lifetime since there is no way to cancel the scope.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea anymore, as it looks like they're just functions for testing (doesn't launch coroutines). Maybe this was an API available previously, but now you should be using `lifecycleScope` to scope a coroutine to a fragment or activity, and `viewModelScope` to scope them to a View Model's life cycle. These are properties available in those classes by already.

Here's what I see when I try to use `launch`:
[image: Possible import suggestions by Android Studio]